# Htaccess :: parameters with a slash instead of slug=

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

**My main URL:**

```
localhost/mypage/
```

**My product URL:**

```
localhost/mypage/single?slug=UJjd94374
```

**My current htaccess code:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**I want my product URL to change to this:**

```
localhost/mypage/single/UJjd94374
```

every time i try to write it i get a 500 server error can someone help me understand how to get my url seo friendly to make to parameters with a slash instead of `slug=`

logs:

```
[Fri Dec 10 16:26:13.919346 2021] [core:error] [pid 22508:tid 1892] [client 127.0.0.1:51785] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: Check what the error log has to say about the reason for the 500 error first of all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
#remove .PHP extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
#Shorten the product URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^mypage/single/(.+)/?$ /mypage/single?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: hi @Amit when i go to `mypage/single?slug=fwytA4xXPNG` it works but when i type `mypage/single/fwytA4xXPNG` it gives a 500 error and when i showed the logs in the post please look at it

Comment: @DB_cont Your error log shows that your rules are generating  an infinite rewrite loop.  Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: nope just your code :: FYI my htaccess is in my htdocs folder, not the project folder does that make a diff? cuz I read something about htaccess being in the project folder rather than htdocs folder.